# Minted tango style with MiKTeX : Unaligned code

Tags: miktex, minted

When using tango style of minted package with MiKTeX (under windows), the code is not properly aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{tango}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{C}
typedef enum
{
  field             = 42,  /* com                               */
  longFieldName     = 42,  /* All your base are belong to us    */
}AnAwsomeType;
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MiKTeX]

Here are the start of the logs:

> LOG FILE : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX
> 21.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.17) 4 FEB 2022 09:58

However, on overleaf, alignment is correct with the exact same code:

[image: Overleaf]

Overleaf log:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.30)  4 FEB 2022 08:56

I noticed that the problem happen only with tango style, but unfortunately this the one I wanna use :(. Using another is a workaround, but does anyone has an idea where it may come from ? Minted ? Pygmentize ? pdflatex version seems the same.

Comment: my guess is that the white space in the original includes tab characters but the overleaf editor has made them spaces which gives more consistent layout, but that's only a guess as this site also turns tabs to spaces so can not tell the difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, Pygments python package was out of date. To update it, for example on a powershell (assuming under windows) :

```
pip install --user --upgrade Pygments
```

It works with the 2.11.2